# Lock service using SQL DataBase

Tags: concurrency, distributed-lock

I have a requirement to synchronize concurrent access to a shared resource modified by different processes which run on different hosts. I am thinking to synchronize this by creating a lock table in a sql database which is accessible from a service that can access the database. All the process will first request for lock from the service and only the one getting the lock will go forward and change the shared resource. Processes will then release the lock after their computation. The lock table will hold information like host, pid, lock creation time of the process currently holding the lock so as to clear the lock if the current process holding the lock has died unexpectedly and some other process has requested for the lock.

I am not inclined for a zookeeper based solution as the traffic in my case is minimal(2-5 process may run in a single day and so the probability of concurrent access is already minimal) and so I am not thinking to maintain a separate service for lock but extend one of the existing service itself by adding an additional table in its database.

I wanted suggestions on this approach or if there is some other simpler solution for this problem.